# SQL find elements is in JSON array column

Tags: sql, json, sql-server, sql-server-2017, json-query

Hello i have a column table who contains json array with tags in it, I try to find a way to select result who contain some of values in it :

| ID | tags |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | ["test01"] |
| 2 | ["test02","test03"] |

I try to used `JSON_QUERY` AND `JSON_VALUE()`:

```
SELECT *
FROM table_tags  
WHERE JSON_QUERY(tags,'$') IN ('test01', 'test02')
```

return nothing

but with json_value on the first array element [0]

```
SELECT *
FROM table_tags  
WHERE JSON_VALUE(tags,'$[0]') IN ('test01', 'test02')
```

it return the first one with test01

| ID | tags |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | ["test01"] |

i need to find a way to iterate through json_value tags to find all tags in ('test01', 'test02')

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Comment: the database is micorosoft SQL server 2017, i just added the tag

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need an `OPENJSON()` call to parse the stored JSON array. The result is a table with columns `key`, `value` and `type` and in the `value` column is each element from the parsed JSON array. The column data type is `nvarchar(max)` with the same collation as `tags` column collation.

```
SELECT *
FROM (VALUES
   (1, '["test01"]'),
   (2, '["test02","test03"]')
) table_tags (id, tags)
WHERE EXISTS (
   SELECT 1 FROM OPENJSON(tags) WHERE [value] IN ('test01', 'test02')
)
```